# I want to run my reddit api script 24/7 but it crashes after 5-6 hours

Tags: python, json, loops, exception, reddit

This is the error im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thevi\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thevi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\thevi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\thevi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thevi\PycharmProjects\Loan Scraper\LoanScraper\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    for post in res.json()['data']['children']:
  File "C:\Users\thevi\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And here is the section of code revolving around it

```
df = pd.read_excel("Scraper.xlsx")


for post in res.json()['data']['children']:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username': [post['data']['author']], 'Return_Amount': [post['data']['title']], 'Mode': [post['data']['title']], "Time_EST": [post['data']['created']],"Time_PST": [post['data']['created']], 'Req_Amount': [post['data']['title']],  'URL': [post['data']['url']],  'Loan ID':post['kind']+ '_' + post['data']['id'], "Location": "" , "Profit": "", "Profit %": ""},  index=[0])
    loan_id = post['kind']+ '_' + post['data']['id']

    if (df['Loan ID'].eq(loan_id)).any():
        print("Duplicate")
        break
    else:
        print("new")
        pass
```

90% of the code runs in a while True loop, can someone please help me out?

I tried looking for solutions online but were of no help

Comment: According to your error message there's a problem decoding the json text in the first character of the first line - there is no value. So looks like you're trying to decode `''`. Try adding some error checking (and handling) code.

Comment: You should add [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to your script.

Comment: here's a print of my json file

Comment: {'kind': 'Listing', 'data': {'after': 't3_z6g47y', 'dist': 25, 'modhash': None,........ the list goes on but as you can see, the first char is not empty.
Also could elaborate on the exception handling with respect to this code, im still relatively new

Comment: How about you read the docs and at least try to implement it?